# I am having issues with my code working properly and im stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem with my code and getting it to work. Im not sure if im sorting this correctly. I am trying to sort with out lambda pandas or itemgetter.

Here is my code that I am having issues with.

```
with open('ManufacturerList.csv', 'r') as man_list:
    ml = csv.reader(man_list, delimiter=',')
    for row in ml:
        manufacturerList.append(row)
        print(row)
with open('PriceList.csv', 'r') as price_list:
    pl = csv.reader(price_list, delimiter=',')
    for row in pl:
        priceList.append(row)
        print(row)
with open('ManufacturerList.csv', 'r') as service_list:
    sl = csv.reader(service_list, delimiter=',')
    for row in sl:
        serviceList.append(row)
        print(row)

new_mfl = (sorted(manufacturerList, key='None'))
new_prl = (sorted(priceList, key='None'))
new_sdl = (sorted(serviceList, key='None'))

for x in range(0, len(new_mfl)):
    new_mfl[x].append(priceList[x][1])

for x in range(0, len(new_mfl)):
    new_mfl[x].append(serviceList[x][1])

new_list = new_mfl
inventoryList = (sorted(list, key=1))
```

i have tried to use the def function to try to get it to work but i dont know if im doing it right. This is what i tried.

```
def new_mfl(x):
    return x[0]


x.sort(key=new_mfl)
```

Comment: `key='None'` won't sort anything. It's not `key=None`! Just remove the parameter. Even `new_mfl` returns `x[0]` which is more or less like natural order sort (no parameter)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What data are you using? What results are you getting? Are they different from the results you expect, and if so, how?

Comment: you have issues understanding how `key` parameter of `sort` works. If you pass a constant, then nothing will be done on your list

Comment: I am trying to sort a csv file and use a key to which links all three files. I am trying to create a new csv file that has all the items sorted

Comment: i know that i can sort it using itemgetter by new_mfl=(sorted(mfl, key=itemgetter(0)))
new_prl=(sorted(prl, key=itemgetter(0)))
new_sdl=(sorted(sdl, key=itemgetter(0)))

Comment: but i am trying to use a basic fuction to sort

Comment: The `key` argument has to be a function, which returns the part of the item that should be compared when sorting. It makes no sense to use a string or number as the key.

Comment: Did you really intend to read the same CSV file for both `manufacturerList` and `serviceList`?

Comment: FYI, you can replace the `for` loops with just `manufacturerList = list(ml)`

Comment: once you have `new_mfl` use [writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) with all data sorted,  by `open('some.csv', 'w', newline='') as file: writer = csv.writer(f) writer.writerows(new_mfl)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def manufacturer_key(x):
    return x[0]

sorted_mfl = sorted(manufacturerList, key=manufacturer_key)
```

The `key` argument is the function that extracts the field of the CSV that you want to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted_mfl = sorted(manufacturerList, key=lambda x: x[0])`

There are different [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) that allow to handle input and output of data from comma separated value files; Maybe it could be used in a way with fewer statements using the correct **delimiter** which depends on the type of data you handle, this would be added to using built in methods like `split` for string data or another method to sort and manipulate `lists`, for example for single column data, `delimiter=','` separate data by comma and it would iterate trough each value and not as a list of lists when you call `csv.reader`

```
['9.310788653967691', '4.065746465800029', '6.6363356879192965', '7.279020237137884', '4.010297786910394'] 
['9.896092029283933', '7.553018448286675', '0.3268282119829197', '2.348011394854333', '3.964531054345021'] 
['5.078622663277619', '4.542467725728741', '3.743648062104161', '12.761916277286993', '9.164698479088221'] 

# out:
             column1             column2             column3             column4             column5
0  4.737897984379577   6.078414943611958  2.7021438955897095  5.8736388919905895   7.878958949784588
1  4.436982168483749  3.9453563399358544   12.66647791861843   5.323017508568736   4.156777982870004
2  4.798241413768279  12.690268531982028   9.638858110105895   7.881360524434767  4.2948334000783195
```

This is achieved because I am using lists that contain singular values, since for columns or lists that are of the form `sorted_mfl = {'First Name' : ['name', 'name', 'name'], 'Second Name ' : [...], 'ID':[...]}, new_prl = ['example', 'example', 'example'] new_sdl = [...]` the data would be added by something like `sorted_mfl + new_prl + new_sdl` and since different modules are also used to set and manage comma separated files, you should add more information to your question like the data type you use or create a [minimal reproducible example with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).